# How to access Cron expression from application.properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks, application.properties

This is my job schedule part and I want to remove the cron trigger, `CronTrigger("0 40 13 * * ?")` then access the cron expression from `application.properties`.

```
@Component
public class DynamicjobSchedule  {

    public void schedulejobs() {

        for (ConnectionStrings obj : listObj) {
            System.out.println("Cron Trigger Starting..");
            scheduler.schedule(new DashboardTask(obj), new CronTrigger("0 40 13 * * ?"));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I create one property file in src/main/resources location and mention the cron expression then call from the scheduler?

Comment: Please consider placing your code here as text, not as an image

Comment: I planned to create cron.property file in src/main/resource location in my project and set cron expression, then i want to use this cron expression in my crontrigger using expression from cron.property file in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation like this:

```
@Component
public class DynamicjobSchedule {

    @Value("${name.of.cron.expression.in.application.properties}")
    private String cronExpression;

    public void schedulejobs() {

        for (ConnectionStrings obj : listObj) {
            System.out.println("Cron Trigger Starting..");
            scheduler.schedule(new DashboardTask(obj), new CronTrigger(cronExpression));
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the `@Value` annotation on method parameter too:

```
@Component
public class DynamicjobSchedule {

    public void schedulejobs(@Value("${name.of.cron.expression.in.application.properties}") String cronExpression) {

        for (ConnectionStrings obj : listObj) {
            System.out.println("Cron Trigger Starting..");
            scheduler.schedule(new DashboardTask(obj), new CronTrigger(cronExpression));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, its working, Use PropertySource annotation on DynamicCronJob, and mention the classpath of property like this PropertySource(classpath:application.property) and Use (value) Annotation that you mentioned about. Its working @nkrivenu